# NodeJs Readline value put into array

Tags: arrays, node.js, readline

I'm using NodeJS readline module to read from a text file. Its returning every line to the console however I want it to add the returned lines to an array. This is the code I got so far, but its not working. I thought the rd.on acted as a sortof for loop but it doesn't look like it. Any help would be appreciated!

```
    function getinfomation2(){
        var firstfile = [];
        var secondfile = [];
        var countvar = 0;
        readline = require('readline');

        var rd = readline.createInterface({
            input: fs.createReadStream('../FixtureProfiles/CFIP1.json'),
            output: process.stdout,
            terminal: false
        });

        // Add fixture details from file to array to later be called
        rd.on('line', function(line) {
            // if fails console.log(line) returns line in console
            firstfile(countvar) = line;
            console.log(firstfile(countvar))
            countvar = countvar +1;
        });
    }
```

Comment: `firstfile(countvar) = line` is incorrect. Array access operators are `[` and `]` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements)). Also check out [`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: Dammit! Your right. Thanks for spotting that. I'm completely wreaked and missed that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firstfile(countvar) = line` is incorrect.

Array access operators are `[` and `]` (see [`Array` docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements)).

Also check out [`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
firstfile.push(line)
```

Comment: Thanks, Up complete missed the array operators. Thanks for pointing that out.